# What close vote did I cast?

Tags: feature-request

When I've cast a close-vote, I can only see how many people voted for what category. Specifically, `off-topic because...` is not a link, so I cannot see why people thought it was off-topic without retracting my close vote.

First off, I want to be able to see what I voted for.
Secondly, I'd like to see the breakdown under `off-topic because...`.

Comment: It's a dupe I ever supported. Having enough upvotes on dupes should imply that feature is a public demand.